# How to pass pointer of derived class to reference to pointer of base class?

Tags: c++

Here is the sample code.

```
class BaseClass {
};

class DerivedClass ： public BaseClass {
};

int Foo(BaseClass*& ptr) {
}

DerivedClass* ptr_to_derived;

//following will not work
Foo(ptr_to_derived);
```

I fail to compile code above, and the error message is "`can't convert DerivedClass* to BaseClass*&`". So How can I pass ptr_to_derived to Foo?

Comment: you could overload `Foo` to accept `DerivedClass*&`

Comment: Why won't it work? Sometimes errors tell you what to do, it at least hint at it. Post the error please.

Comment: @TarickWelling There are many derived class here, and I want to use polymorphism here.

Comment: If you could do that, `Foo` could say `ptr = new BaseClass;`, and then `ptr_to_derived` would no longer point to a `DerivedClass`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Do you mean ptr_to_derived = new BaseClass?

Comment: @hexiecs No, `Foo`'s parameter is called "ptr". `ptr_to_derived = new BaseClass;` would not compile.

Comment: `std::pair<int, BaseClass*> Foo()` would be more intuitive signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   ‘`BaseClass*&`’ from an rvalue of type ‘`BaseClass*`’

Because `Foo` takes a pointer by non-const reference you can't pass it an rvalue. The implicit conversion from `DerivedClass` to `BaseClass` that happens when you pass it to `Foo` gets you the rvalue that the error is complaining about.

You can create a base pointer from the derived one and pass that:

```
DerivedClass* ptr_to_derived;
BaseClass* ptr_derived_base = ptr_to_derived;

Foo(ptr_derived_base);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.

What you can do is convert to a pointer to a base, store that converted pointer somewhere (such as variable), and pass that by lvalue reference. The reference cannot refer to the derived pointer. Like so:

```
BaseClass* ptr_to_base = ptr_to_derived;
Foo(ptr_to_base);
```

However, it would be better to pass the pointer by value in order to avoid this hassle. Or preferably even pass a reference instead of a pointer to the base in case that is sufficient. Like so:

```
int Foo(BaseClass& ref)
```

With this you can call:

```
DerivedClass1 d1;
DerivedClass2 d2;
Foo(d1);
Foo(d2);

// or with pointers
DerivedClass1* d1_ptr = &d1;
DerivedClass2* d2_ptr = &d2;
Foo(*d1_ptr);
Foo(*d2_ptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Foo` might modify the passed pointer-to-base. For example:

```
class OtherDerivedClass : public BaseClass {
};

OtherDerivedClass* ptr_to_other_derived = ...;

void Foo(BaseClass*& ptr)
{
    ptr = ptr_to_other_derived;
}
```

What do you think should happen if you could call this `Foo` with `ptr_to_derived`? Should `ptr_to_derived` now point not to a `DerivedClass` but to an `OtherDerivedClass` object? That's wrong on every level.

**Solution 1:** Don't allow `Foo` to modify the pointer. Either pass by value:

```
void Foo(BaseClass* ptr)
```

or by const-ref:

```
void Foo(const BaseClass*& ptr)
```

**Solution 2:** Create a pointer-to-base variable that `Foo` can modify.

```
BaseClass* ptr_to_base = ptr_to_derived;
foo(ptr_to_base);
```

This will of course leave `ptr_to_derived` unmodified. C++ does not let you pass a temporary expression (which is what the conversion from `DerivedClass*` to `BaseClass*` would return) because, again, `Foo` says it will modify that pointer and the changed temporary would just be discarded. That's usually a mistake. You could of course still decide to not care about the change to `ptr_to_base` that `Foo` might make.

Answer (score 1):

This is illegal for good reasons, look at following code:

```cpp
class BaseClass {};

class DerivedClass ：public BaseClass {};
class DerivedClass2 ：public BaseClass {};

DerivedClass2 derived2;

void Foo(BaseClass*& ptr) {
    ptr = &derived2; // Legal.
}

DerivedClass* ptr_to_derived = nullptr;
```

then if legal, `Foo(ptr_to_derived)` would make `ptr_to_derived` to unrelated `DerivedClass2` which is wrong.